# Adding field which is not in model

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

I have just started using Odoo and i am creating my own module, so i added a new field to Products for example:

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    netto_price = fields.Float()
```

now i will have few extra field which change based on netto_price and netto_price will change based on them. Basicaly all of them are calculated from netto_price. Now i tryed to add another field:

```
<field name="calculated_price"/>
```

But as its not in model it crash. So any ideas how i woul be able to add it? I tryed with input field (html) but when i am not add edit mode there is still input field which is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from openerp import api

class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    netto_price = fields.Float()
    calculated_price = fields.Float('Calculated price') # or whatever type you want it to be

    @api.onchange('netto_price')
    def netto_change(self):

        return {value: {'calculated_price': self.netto_price}}
```

Basically what you need to do is add the new field `calculated`, and then decorate any function you want to be triggered when a particular field is changed with `api.onchange` passing in the field that you want to trigger the function as the first argument, and in this function i just set the value of `calculated_price` to that of `netto`

Comment: Okay so this means that i must save calculated_price to database too? There is no way i would just calculate it and display?

Comment: No you don't have to set the `store` attribute to false `calculated_price = fields.Float('calculated price', store=False`)